# Filter network traffic in a script

Tags: linux, networking, firewall

which programming language do I have to learn to control the traffic passing my Raspberry Pi? I'm interested in using if-statements, so that the script decides, if the client is authorised to receive data-packets, and if not, then don't send/reject the data packet.

So which programming language do you recommend for my project, running on Ubuntu?

Comment: To control network traffic on Linux systems, use `iptables`. https://crybit.com/what-is-iptables-in-linux/

Comment: @Jan I need to check every package ... destination, source, ... and if the client/the destination is authorised, then accept the package, else reject it. I don't see there a possibility with iptables.

Comment: Accept all packages for predefined hosts and reject all other packages using iptables rules. I think this would work, but maybe you need to describe your usecase in more detail...

Comment: @Jan A user has to authenticate using Browser before using my Internet. Before authentificating every other package should be rejected, only if user is logged in, the package must be checked and logged.